# How Can I Scrape Twitter Now That They Require JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, xpath, twitter

I have a couple sites that monitor Twitter for specific types of statements and scrape relevant Tweets using curl in PHP. A few days ago those sites stopped scraping Twitter. I figured they probably redesigned the layout of their mobile.twitter site and all I would have to do is change my xPath query to a different class or something, but instead I found out that whenever you try to visit Twitter without JavaScript enabled you are given a prompt to enable JavaScript to access Twitter. There seems to be no way around this. Before this change one could access a version of Twitter that did not require JavaScript, so I could scrape Tweets with a simple curl request and xPath query.

I have searched Google for ways to enable JavaScript support for curl request but have found nothing. Is it possible to add something to a curl request to parse JavaScript or do I need to find soem other solution?

Comment: The web is open, free and standardized. Twitter uses it because it has a domain and services on it, so Twitter must follow the internet rules first. Twitter can add any ToS that are not against web rules, but on this point, Twitter does not respect the web standard, so you have the right to bypass this point. And it's explicity legal in France for many reasons (accessibilty, freedom, equality, obsolescence, etc.). 
If Twitter doesn't want anybody access the tweets of anybody, Twitter can restrict access for all people. As long as tweets are free to read, anybody can use any means to read it.

Comment: I don't think that the web is closed and limited to people who have money, but it's not the main point. Just because some kill other people with knives doesn't mean nobody can explain how to forge it or how to cook with it. Here, my aim is not to steal the data managed by Twitter, but just to be able to display my own thread on my own public site. It must be done in backend for archival and accessibility purpose. And there are many other good and not illegal reasons to be able to scrape data from Twitter. So the solution is described in the comment of @kdcode, so it's just a few lines of code.

Comment: And this evidence to be free to scrap any public site is not only legal in Europe, but recognized legal by a USA appeals court too (https://techcrunch.com/2022/04/18/web-scraping-legal-court/).

Answer (score 4):

You can not "Enable" JavaScript on curl. It is not a browser, it only does HTTP requests. Have you considered using the Twitter API?

You can also intercept XHRs on twitter using your browser's development tools and work your way through them to figure out what HTTP request you need to make in order to get the data you want.

Another solution is to use an scriptable "headless" browser. check out CapsperJS. Simply put it is a fully functional browser that does not show any UI and you can control it via JS.

Comment: I have tried sites like Social Searcher that use the Twitter API but they will only do 100 requests a day and the most you can do a month for over $20 is 800. I really need something that is not API dependent. That was nice about scraping Twitter directly because my site would find many relevant posts a day but would have to do far more searches. It could copy between 5-10,000 posts per month. I also don't want my access to Twitter dependent on their permission, so crawling pages is preferable to API access for that reason too.

Comment: Then consider doing a bit reverse engineering to finally be able to do the same requests the JavaScript code of twitter does yourself using curl. Basically it calls into some API to get some JSON while passing cookies for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

There are many free endpoints available that can help solve this, rather than having to scrape the webpage. If you're looking for specific Tweets, try the new v2. Search API: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/introduction

You just need to have an approved developer account.

Comment: Of course, it's easy with the api and a token. But this is not the solution, because in many cases, it's not possible to have a developer token. My users don't have such an account, they are not able to ask for such an account, they are not developers, etc. And it's very complex to get (for example, it is required to have a phone that is not on another account).

Comment: then build a webpage that your users access. Your webpages does the call to the api, using the dev-account. Your users do not need these credentials. (only maybe the credentials to access _your_ site.

Comment: 2023 update: Twitter are apparently scrapping ALL free access to the API (as of Thursday 9th February 2023, in 2 days' time); but haven't provided any further detail, including pricing or authorisation as of yet. So... good luck? ‍♀️

Answer (score 2):

You need to render page with javascript, to get final html. You can use phantomjs (headless browser) for that purpose. Here is php plugin: http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

Comment: Indeed, it's probably the best solution for php, since it avoids reverse engineering proposed by @kdcode. Ask to PostAlmostAnything to select this answer as the good one.

Comment: Nevertheless, the default config of phantomjs does not work and Twitter is not detecting that js is enabled.

Comment: This package is 2 years old. You may check if it works in the latest phantomjs release.
Try following https://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html and check if twitter loads.

Comment: @Daniel-KM if you checked it please tell us if updating phantom resolved your problem!

Comment: See above https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998354/7103991.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the dev account is not required and an anonymous authorization bearer token is enough for now. This token is provided by Twitter itself inside the main app js.

For an example of implementation, see the snippet https://gitlab.com/Daniel-KM/Omeka-S-module-BlockPlus/-/snippets/2068979.

Comment: (Re: Your code on Github). Dude you rock. Exactly what I was looking for. Take it down before people abuse it and Twitter catches on.

Comment: This method no longer seems to work -- likely that the bearer token no longer has the required permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this video from Traversy Media

Real-Time Tweets & Socket.io Project | Twitter Streaming API

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjjjhGW4ceM

Source code:

https://github.com/bradtraversy/real-time-tweet-stream

Comment: As other responses, it requires a dev token. And with the dev token, the endpoint is already available, so a specific library is useless.